# Merge histories of two files from same git repository

Tags: git

I have two files, `./asm.py` and `dir/asm.py`.

`A -> B -> C -> D -> master`

I worked on `./asm.py` for a couple of commits, let's say up to commit `C`. For reasons I don't know, at commit `C` I added a new file - `dir/asm.py`, which is exactly the same as `./asm.py`at that point. Further commits `C->D->master` are all upon `dir/asm.py`.

Obviously, histories of these two files are not connected. `./asm.py` is developed for `A->B` and `dir/asm.py` is developed in `C->D->master`. I'm wondering if I can somehow combine those two so I get `A->B->C->D->master` when I look at the history of `dir/asm.py`, and then remove `./asm.py`

Comment: It's worth noting here that Git literally does not have file history. Git has commits, and the commits *are* the history. To make up a history about some particular file, `git log` (which *will* do this) fakes it: it looks at the commits, sees which ones "touch" some file, and claims that this limited subset of commits is the "file history". That's often what you want, but don't mistake it for reality, because sometimes it isn't what you want—as in your own case!

Comment: If you had removed `./asm.py` in commit `D`, and ran `git log --follow dir/asm.py`, Git would compare commits `C` and `D` and see that in `C`, there is an `asm.py`, while in `D`, there is no `asm.py` but there is `dir/asm.py`. Given that they have identical content (which means Git de-duplicated the files), Git would be able to tell instantly that these are the same *content*. So `git log --follow` would, at that point, stop looking for `dir/asm.py` and start looking instead for `asm.py`. This would give you the faked-up "file history" that you *do* want.

Comment: Alas, that's not quite what you have right now. See [TTT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047063/1256452) for a way to add yet more commits in which this does happen (so these commits have that as their commit history, and if `git log --follow` were to follow these commits backwards, you'd see what you want).

Comment: (I think I just used the wrong pair of commits, C and D, instead of B and C above, but hopefully the idea is clear!)

Comment: @torek I tried it before posting the question, and I couldn't quite replicate that behaviour as I had the same mindset.
thanks for input though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to insert a new commit between `B` and `C` that does a move of the file. Then cherry-pick the rest of the commits in order from `C` through `master`.

It may be easier to try it out on a new temporary branch:

```
git switch -c temp-branch B # where B is the commit ID
# now move the file manually into the dir folder, and commit it
# When done, cherry-pick the remaining commit range:
git cherry-pick C..master
# you'll likely get a conflict here saying the file was deleted- accept the delete
# To continue the cherry-pick:
git cherry-pick --continue
# it should finish without additional conflicts
# Look at the history of the file and make sure you're happy with it
# Rename your branch to master
git branch -M master
```

Note, the reason you can do this is because you didn't modify the file after you created a copy of it.

Comment: Disclaimer: I wrote this answer without testing any of it so there might be a syntax bug...I'll test it out later when I get a chance, if you haven't confirmed it by then.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Agreed. I considered rebase first: reset master to B, commit the move, then rebase --onto from C to previous master commit ID (and then if detached switch -C back into master). But I think most people seem to find cherry picking a range conceptually easier to understand than rebase --onto.